# Unparseable date error

Tags: java, android, parseexception

I have this

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu, 21 Apr 2016 18:00:00
>   +0000" (at offset 26)

when using new `SimpleDateFormat("E, dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm:ss a", Locale.ROOT);`

Why is that can be?

**EDIT:**

This is correct answer due to parsing pattern.

```
SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.ROOT);
```

And also Android somehow gives error when the Locale is `ROOT` and when it is `ENGLISH` everything works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong format. You should be using `EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z` instead of `E, dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm:ss a`.

Here is the code snippet:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception
{
    String foo = "Thu, 21 Apr 2016 18:00:00 +0000";
    SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.ROOT);
    System.out.println(f.parse(foo));
}
```

Output:

```
Thu Apr 21 18:00:00 GMT 2016
```

Comment: I don't understand why it happens but it works at emulator but fails at real devices - giving this error. It is in asynktask by the way

Answer (score 2):

Use `EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z`

Comment: I don't understand why it happens but it works at emulator but fails at real devices - giving this error. It is in asynktask by the way